# How to create new columns in a pandas dataframe based on another categorical variable/column and it's corresponding value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a Python Pandas Dataframe like below :

[Original Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqtZI.png)

I want to create a Dataframe like this, where the Subject-wise Marks are in separate Columns :

[Desired Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqOZt.png)

I have tried groupby and agg, but I could not arrive at the desired solution :

[Groupby Agg Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qP34.png)

Request you to kindly help me regarding the same, if possible.

Thank you.